# Why BindingFlags are called so?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

Coming from WPF background,just wondering, why BindingFlags in `Reflection` are called so? 
What is so "binding" about it?

Comment: I did google, but didn't find any answer. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I found loads of resources - https://www.google.com/search?q=why+BindingFlags+in+Reflection+are+called+so%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8. Try just starting at the `Binder` page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.binder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Enigmativity, yeah you are right! But when you are so much already so engrossed in "WPF binding", and suddenly you see "binding" somewhere else,  the mind always tricks so badly that it's so hard to comprehend what else it's trying to say. I was just trying to connect the dots and make sense, although I know how to use it  and what it does generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the class that translates the metadata to a actual method is called [`Binder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.binder(v=vs.110).aspx) and `BindingFlags` are flags that are passed on to the binder to connect to the method.

Comment: So, what does the `Binder` bind to?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.binder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It does not "bind to" anything, it (to quote the MSDN) "Selects a member from a list of candidates, and performs type conversion from actual argument type to formal argument type." Or in other terms it chooses which method overload to return based on the data you passed

Comment: But there is nothing "binding" about it except `type` conversion from `actual` to `formal` argument types.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: "Bind" means more than just WPF binding. In the general form it just means "Connect together", here the binder is connecting metadata to a actual method call. As for a example, go read the MSDN the Remarks section show examples of what uses it.

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site.  It's not somewhere for you to learn the finer points of the English language that possible meanings of specific words.

Comment: Thanks to @ScottChamberlain actually taking time and explaining.